# Cannot deploy a build in heroku (NODEJS)

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a build in heroku but isn't not possible, the console stays like this for a long time when it supposed to deploy immediately.

```
Enumerating objects: 12, done.
Counting objects: 100% (12/12), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Writing objects: 100% (9/9), 1.22 KiB | 124.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 9 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
```

Herkou web says this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku services is down for some reasons now https://status.heroku.com/